# How would i apply multiple function over an element and store the element itself for a custom graph in javascript?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am trying to create a graph for some links , when you click them to count the clicks and also in the same time Create a new element, more specific a DIV element itself. Now first i will add the code so that you can have a better look on it and then try to explain. My

index.html

```
<input type="submit" id="btn" value="add element"><br><br><br>

<input type="submit" id="inc" value="increase element"><br><br><br><br>

<p id="result"></p>

<div id="box"></div>

 <script src="main.js"></script>
```

as for the css i have this code, just basic styling

```
    #box{
    position: absolute;;
    bottom: 10px;
    left:0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: red;

}
.div{
    margin-left: 10px;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: 380px;
    display: inline-block;
    width:10px;
    height: 0px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Now the java script file that i have for main.js is this one :

```
    var btn=document.getElementById("btn");
var box=document.getElementById("box");
var link=document.getElementById("inc");

var para=document.getElementById("result");


btn.onclick=function(){

    var div=document.createElement("div");

    div.classList.add("div");

    div.setAttribute("class","div");

    box.appendChild(div);

    var click=0;

    link.onclick=function(){


        var setClick=click++;


        var h=div.offsetHeight;

        var newheight=1;

        div.style.height=h+newheight+"px";;

        para.innerHTML=setClick;

      }
}
```

Now what the goal of this code is :

1) I am trying to create a new element whenever i  press the input button add element which creates a new Div element in the div with the id "box". After that

2) i am trying to increase the height of that newly created div always dynamically by 5px or any other value by clicking the next input button increase element. Which means for each div that i create separately.

3) and after that what i want to do is to store those values in local storage , whether it is suitable or maybe not so that after refresh i want loos the div box together with the click count .

Now the code works well except that i am running to some issues .
The first problem occurs when i create the first div , it increase the height normally upwards until the click 15 which then starts the increase the height downwards, the other divs  that are created are ruining normally. As for the other problem the click always.
So please could someone help me out with the coding and tell me weather i do something wrong and how to correct that. What would be the steps by creating such a code with avoiding.
Thanks anyone for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem might be due to the relative positioning of the created divs. I refactored your code a bit. This might work the way you were looking for.

I disabled the increase button until the first click of the add button.

The div class (renamed to bar) is absolutely positioned. Their `left` attribute gets set on creation. An inline-block display isn't necessary anymore.

In the script I added a variable `numDiv` to count the created divs and use that as an id to change the height of the last div created.

```js
var btn=document.getElementById("btn");
var box=document.getElementById("box");
var link=document.getElementById("inc");
var para=document.getElementById("result");

let click = 0;
let numDiv = -1;
btn.onclick=function(){
    link.disabled = false;
    click = 0;
    para.innerHTML=click;
    let div=document.createElement("div");
    div.classList.add("bar");
    numDiv++; 
    div.id = 'div'+numDiv;
    div.style.left = 20 * numDiv + 'px';
    box.appendChild(div);
}
link.onclick=function(){
  click++;
  document.getElementById('div'+numDiv).style.height = click+'px';
  para.innerHTML=click;
}
```

```css
#box{
    position: absolute;;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
.bar{
    margin-left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width:10px;
    height: 0px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btn" value="add element">
<input type="button" disabled='true' id="inc" value="increase element">
<p id="result">0</p>
<div id="box"></div>
```

Comment: Danke dir seher Michael  , Du hast mir seher viele geholfen  und ich habe von dir etwas neues gelernt. I just learned that you can directly append the id to the newly created element in my case the div.id='div'+numDiv;. I have just two question : why did you set the numDiv variable to -1 , and what is the most appropriate way to store these values into session or local storage , and what values should i store . Danke dir nocheinmal fur die hilfe und viele grusse nach meine heimeit Salzburg.

Comment: The numDiv was set to -1 because I increase it before I use it as the ID and I wanted it to start at 0. If you'd like to store values in the browsers cacha you could check out the `window.localStorage` functions `getItem` and `setItem`. You would have to refactor your code though and store the heights of all created divs.
I can recommend checking out freeCodeCamp.org. They'll cover a lot of html/css/javascript related topics.